# Is it possible/required to speed up HashMap operations on same entry?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Suppose I wish to check `HashMap` entry and then replace it:

```
if( check( hashMap.get(key) ) ) {
    hashMap.put(key, newValue);
}
```

this will cause search procedure inside `HashMap` to run two times: once while `get` and another one while `put`. This looks ineffective. Is it possible to modify value of already found entry of Map?

**UPDATE**

I know I can make a wrapper and I know I have problems to mutate entry. But the question is WHY? May be `HashMap` remembers last search to improve repeated one? Why there are no methods to do such operation?

Comment: AFAIK, `put` will automatically replace the old value for existing key.

Comment: If you haven't seen an ill effect while profiling, I would imagine the inefficiency is very small.  But I believe the answer is no.  With a `TreeMap` you might be able to, if its `Map.Entry` supports `setValue()`, but `TreeMap` has its own performance differences.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes, but this looks like `check()` is some user-defined function. If you just `put` the new stuff in, you may have to roll back later.

Comment: @Rob if the map is very big the search can be very long, and twice search can cost.

Comment: @Suzan - no, I believe `get()` should be constant time with a `HashMap`, thus not really related to size of the map (unless the `hashCode()` is broken).

Comment: What 'search' are you referring to exactly? The search that occurs in the case of hash code collisions? If this is a problem in your app then thats the problem you should be trying to solve. `get` and `put` operations in hash maps are constant time operations - (o(1)).

Comment: Rob is right get and put for HashMap is constant-time.

Comment: Note that it's only constant time assuming an insignificant number of hash collisions. If you use a really lousy hash so that *all* entries have the same hash, it's O(N) of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Strictly speaking, what you are describing wouldn't be considered a hash table. Hash uniformity is a (unenforceable) requirement of any hashing function.

Comment: @Perception: I was talking about `HashMap` and hash codes in the real world, not a theoretical hash table. And anyway, even if the hash is *globally* uniform across all possible values, you could still happen to use keys which gave the same hash code.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I've just discovered that you *can* modify the entry, via [`Map.Entry.setValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#setValue%28V%29) (and the `HashMap` implementation is mutable). It's a pain to get the entry for a particular key though, and I can't remember ever seeing anyone do this. You can get a *set* of the entries, but you can't get the entry for a single key, as far as I can tell.

There's one *evil* way of doing it - declare your own subclass of `HashMap` within the `java.util` package, and create a *public* method which just delegates to the package-private existing method:

```
package java.util;

// Please don't actually do this...
public class BadMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    public Map.Entry<K, V> getEntryPublic(K key) {
        return getEntry(key);
    }
}
```

That's pretty nasty though.

You wouldn't normally modify the *entry* - but of course you can change data within the value, if that's a mutable type.

I very much doubt that this is *actually* a performance bottleneck though, unless you're doing this a heck of a lot. You should profile your application to prove to yourself that this is a real problem before you start trying to fine-tune something which is probably not an issue.

If it *does* turn out to be an issue, you could change (say) a `Map<Integer, String>` into a `Map<Integer, AtomicReference<String>>` and use the `AtomicReference<T>` as a simple mutable wrapper type.

Comment: Actually, you CAN modify the entry: Map.Entry.setValue(V).  Problem is getting the reference to the Map.Entry to do that with.

Comment: @sharakan: Yes, I've just noticed that. Fixing!

Comment: Instead of a `MutableWrapper<String>` you can have `AtomicReference<String>` or just `String[]`

Comment: @PeterLawrey: True. Will update to `AtomicReference` as a cleaner option IMO than an array.

Comment: How can't it be bottleneck if the map is very big?

Comment: @SuzanCioc: Because a hash map lookup is amortized O(1). That's the whole point of a hash map.

Comment: It doesn't matter how big the map is; hash table lookups are always really fast -- so why bend over backwards to avoid one extra (cheap) lookup?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Unless you have *really* bad hash collisions ;)

Comment: Well or if you need to do the lookup for many entries. Then it's actually also independent of the map's size ;-) see what i mean? The Map's size doesn't matter for a single lookup, but what if the amount of lookups is dependent on the map's size? The OP didn't exactly tell us his use case, so we can't know, but i would guess there is a correlation between the map's size and how many operations he wants to perform on the map's entries.

Comment: @kutschkem: Each lookup is O(1) independently though. Yes, if you want to do lots of lookups that will take longer - but there's nothing to *suggest* that it would depend on the size of the map, so I don't think it's useful to connect the two.

Comment: Well if the OP sees the double lookup as problem, i infer he does lots of those. I would really like to see what he's doing that causes him to think the lookups are a problem.

Comment: @kutschkem: I don't think there's any actual evidence that this is causing a problem at the moment. There's an *expectation* on the part of the OP that it's a problem, but that's a different matter.

Answer (score 2):

Too much information for a comment on your question. Check the documentation for Hashmap.

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic
>   operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the
>   elements properly among the buckets. Iteration over collection views
>   requires time proportional to the "capacity" of the HashMap instance
>   (the number of buckets) plus its size (the number of key-value
>   mappings). Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity
>   too high (or the load factor too low) if iteration performance is
>   important.

Constant time means that it always requires the same amount of time to do the get and put operations [O(1)]. The amount of time that is going to be required is going to be linear based on how many times you need to loop [O(n)].

Comment: The only sane answer in the bunch, you sir, get a +1.

Comment: @Perception, Thank you. I was beginning to wonder what it was in my years of using HashMap that I had been missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the entry if it is mutable. One example of where you might do this is

```
private final Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public void put(String key, String value) {
    List<String> list = map.get(key);
    if (list == null)
        map.put(key, list = new ArrayList<>());
    list.add(value);
}
```

This allows you to update a value, but you can't find and replace a value in one operation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at trove ( http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/ ), their maps do have several methods that might be what you want:

- adjustOrPut
- putIfAbsent

I don't know how this is implemented internally, but i would guess that since trove is made to be highly performant, there will be only one lookup.